# If $Y\sim\mathcal N_{X,\:\sigma^2}$ and $Z\sim\mathcal N_{Y,\:\sigma^2}$, can we show that $Z\sim\mathcal N_{X,\:2\sigma^2}$?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

Let $\sigma>0$ and note that $$(x,B)\in\mathbb R\times\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\mapsto\mathcal N_{x,\:\sigma^2}(B)\;\;\;\text{for }$$ is a Markov kernel on $\left(\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\right)$. Now let $X,Y,Z$ be real-valued random variables on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ with $$\operatorname P\left[Y\in B\mid X\right]=\mathcal N_{X,\:\sigma^2}(B)\;\;\;\text{almost surely for all }B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\tag1$$ and $$\operatorname P\left[Z\in B\mid Y\right]=\mathcal N_{Y,\:\sigma^2}(B)\;\;\;\text{almost surely for all }B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\tag2$$ and $$\operatorname P\left[Z\in B\mid X\right]=\mathcal N_{X,\:2\sigma^2}(B)\;\;\;\text{almost surely for all }B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)\tag3?$$ We know that the sum of independent normally  distributed random variables is again normally distributed with accumulated mean and variance. Can we use this here somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Let me attempt this.

Write:
$$
Y = U_1 + \alpha (X - E(X)) + X \\
$$
where $U_1 \sim N(0, \sigma_1^2)$  and $X$, $U_1$ are not correlated.

Because $Y \sim N(.,.)$, if $X$ is not normally distributed, then $\alpha=0$ and $U_1 \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$.

But if  $X$ is normally distributed, it is still true that $\alpha=0$ and $U_1 \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. That is because if $\alpha \ne 0$, then $var(Y|X) \ne \sigma^2$, contradicting $P[Y∈B∣X]=N(X,\sigma^2)$.

Similarly,  we can let $Z = U_2 + \beta (Y -E(Y)) + Y$, where $ U_2 \sim N(0,\sigma_2^2)$ and show $\beta=0$.

So:
$$
Y = U_1 + X \\
Z = U_2 +  Y
$$

Let $U = U_1 + U_2$, then  $U \sim N(0, 2\sigma^2)$.

This can further be written as:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Z &= (U_2 + U_1) + X \\
 &= U + X \\
 & \sim N(0, 2\sigma^2) + X \\
& \sim N(X, 2\sigma^2)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The crucial point is the independence of $U_1$ and $U_2$. How do you prove that?

Comment: edited my answer to show this.

Comment: @TomBennett $Z = U_2 \pmb{+ +} \beta (Y -E(Y) )+  Y$ would not be $Z = U_2  \pmb{+} \beta (Y -E(Y) )+  Y$?

Comment: sorry. typo and fixed. I obviously can't type on my phone.

Comment: further clarified

Comment: Sorry, for replying to this old post, but you still haven't shown that $U_1$ and $U_2$ are independent (which you seem to assume in order to conclude that their sum is normal distributed).

Comment: Yes it does. For a normal distribution, independence is the same as being uncorrelated.

Comment: But where did you show that $U_1$ and $U_2$ are uncorrelated? (BTW, you need to "@" me. Otherwise I don't get notified.)

Comment: I just let $U_1, U_2$ be random variables not correlated to anything and use the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ terms to capture possible correlations. .